# Proving an Equation is Always Positive

Tags: trigonometry

I'm doing some algorithms research and I need to prove that a large equation (obtained from taking a partial derivative) is always positive. I'm not a mathematician so I haven't been able to make heads or tails of it.

Is there any way to show that the following equation is greater than zero
\begin{align*}
&-b \sin(t -a t + 2 r ) 
\\ &+ \sin(a t - t + 2 b (\pi - r - t) ) 
\\ &+ b \sin(t + a t + 2 r ) 
\\ &- \sin(t+at  + 2b(\pi - r - t) ) 
\\ &+ (b+1) \sin(t - a t) 
\\ &+ (1-b)\sin(t+at)
\end{align*}

if we know the following information for the variables
\begin{alignat*}{2}
0&<a& &<1 
\\ 0&<b& &<1
\\ 0^{\circ}&<t& &<45^{\circ}
\\ 0^{\circ}&<r& &<45^{\circ}
\end{alignat*}

I broke the equation into individual components to make it more readable, but so far I don't know if there's a strong enough connection between components (lines) of the equation to say that the result is always positive, though I suspect it will be.

Comment: I would use some trigonometric identities to try to reduce the number of terms.

Comment: FYI, the expression (upon dividing by $4$, which doesn't affect the sign) reduces to $$\sin \left(\;b (\pi - r - t)\;\right) \sin t \sin\left(\;b (\pi - r - t) + a t\;\right)-b \sin r \sin(a t) \sin(r + t)$$

Comment: It might help if you could provide the context from which this expression arises. There may be a clear geometric reason for it to be positive.

Comment: @Blue it's complicated, the best I could do in short is saying that as you increase one of the base angles of a triangle from 0 to 45 degrees, the height of that triangle and subsequent triangles (whose base sides are the non-base sides of the the initial triangle) will strictly increase. That said, how did you come up with that equation by dividing by 4? You don't have to derive it but generally how does that work?

Comment: @RoryHector: The ["sum-to-product" identities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) collapse various pairs of terms in your expression into products. For instance, $$-b \sin(t - a t + 2 r) + b \sin(t + a t + 2 r)=2 b \cos(2 r + t) \sin(a t)$$ After a couple of passes, the expression collapses to what I wrote above, but with an extra factor of $4$. I divided-out that factor simply to reduce a bit of visual clutter in the final expression.

Comment: @Blue, that's really helpful. Thank you, I'll look into it.