# A Trigonometric Reduction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to prove an equation is always positive given certain constraints for the variables, the equation I've come up with is as follows

$ 2 b \cos(t+2r) \sin(a t) - 2 \sin(t) \cos(a t + 2 b (\pi - r - t)) + 2 \sin(t) \cos(a t) - 2 b \cos(t) \sin(a t)$

In my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030274) it is [commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030274/proving-an-equation-is-always-positive#comment6249018_3030274) that this expression can be simplified to the following equation

$ \sin(b(\pi-r-t)) \sin(t) \sin(b(\pi - r - t) + a t) - b \sin(r) \sin(a t) \sin(r+t)$

Is this correct and if so, how did they do it? Like I said, I'm not a mathematician so I haven't been able to recreate it but if this is true it could prove useful.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the RHS is zero right? The coefficient seems to be canceled out.

\begin{align}
& 2 b \cos(t+2r) \sin(a t) - 2 \sin(t) \cos(a t + 2 b (\pi - r - t)) + 2 \sin(t) \cos(a t) - 2 b \cos(t) \sin(a t)\\
&= 2 b [\cos(t+2r)- \cos(t)] \sin(a t) -2[\cos(a t)-\cos(a t + 2 b (\pi - r - t))]\sin(t)\\
&= -4b\sin(r)\sin(r+t)\sin(at) -4 \sin(b (-r - t + π)) \sin(a t + b (-r - t + π))\sin(t)\\
&=-4\left[b\sin(r)\sin(r+t)\sin(at) + \sin(b (-r - t + π)) \sin(a t + b (-r - t + π))\sin(t)\right]
\end{align}

Discarding the $(-4)$, you get your expression. This is just using a standard [product/sum formula](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/prodform/prodform.html).

Comment: Thank you very much but I think there is a mistake on the second line should it be $2 b [ \cos(t+2 r) - \cos(t)] \sin(a t) + 2[\cos(a t) - \cos(a t + 2 b(\pi - r - t))] \sin(t)$ which I think would cause the final result to be $\sin(b(\pi-r-t)) \sin(t) \sin(b(\pi - r - t) + a t) - b \sin(r) \sin(a t) \sin(r+t)$ after getting rid of a factor of 4